# Error while initializing Cipher

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have function that crypts string:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

public String encryptValueWithBlowfish(String data, String secretKey) {

    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    try {
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(decoder.decodeBuffer(secretKey), "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/NoPadding", "BC");
        String iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
        IvParameterSpec ivs = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivs);
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        return encoder.encode(sha.digest(cipher.doFinal(decoder.decodeBuffer(data))));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        lg.info("Failed to encryptValueWithBlowfish: " + e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
}
```

Line `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivs);` rises exception  `"Unsupported keysize or algorithm parameters"`. This code forks fine in another Linux machine. Parameters passed in both cases are the same. I'm not strong in crypto things. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> What might be wrong?

Well, you're using the default character encoding here: `iv.getBytes()` - that's never a good start. Perhaps the two different machines have different default encodings.

If you want to create a byte array of all-zeroes and a particular size, why not just use:

```
IvParameterSpec ivs = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
```

Or use 16 if you wanted a 16 byte IV.

It's not clear what `decoder` is here - but you use it twice and again, if that's using the default character encoding it could vary by machine.

Comment: Hello, after changing to IvParameterSpec ivs = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]); still have the same excepton. I have updated decoder and encoder declaration in problem description

Comment: @user1501700: Are your `data` and `secretKey` genuinely base64 data?